# Jasper Report : set background color of an element

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to add a background color to a frame.
Here is how I did :

```
<frame>
     <reportElement x="-10" y="100" width="560" height="150" forecolor="rgba(148, 119, 118, 0.47058824)" backcolor="rgba(116, 184, 95, 0.62352943)" uuid="33624d2d-2285-4a6a-a3f4-96546c05bfa8"/>
</frame>
```

But when my report is display, no color shows.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should set the element as `Opaque`.

```
<reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-10" y="100" width="560" height="150" forecolor="rgba(148, 119, 118, 0.47058824)" backcolor="rgba(116, 184, 95, 0.62352943)" uuid="33624d2d-2285-4a6a-a3f4-96546c05bfa8"/>
```